# Typing right to left and add comma to thousand value on TextBox?

Tags: c#

I have a TextBox where and I want to type values right to left and add comma. I want to add comma to thousand values and I want to format the values when I to type.

How could I do this ?

trying.

```
public class AddCommaToThousand {
        private TextBox txtBox;
        private String txt = string.Empty;
        private Double valor = 0;

        public AddCommaToThousand(TextBox txtBox) {
            this.txtBox = txtBox;
            this.txtBox.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;            
            this.txtBox.Text = "1,000";
            this.txtBox.KeyPress += keyPress;
            this.txtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textChanged);            
            this.txtBox.Font = new Font(this.txtBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);            
        }

        private void textChanged(object obj, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                txt = txtBox.Text.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "");
                if (txt.Length == 0) {
                    txtBox.Text = "1,000";
                }
                txt = txt.PadLeft(4, '0');
                if (txt.Length > 4 && txt.Substring(0, 1) == "0")
                    txt = txt.Substring(1, txt.Length - 1);
                valor = Convert.ToDouble(txt);
                txtBox.Text = string.Format("{0:N}", valor);
                txtBox.SelectionStart = txtBox.Text.Length;                
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }        
        }

        private void keyPress(object obj, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
            if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))) { e.Handled = true; }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To align the text to the right, use

```
txtBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

To add the commas you can either use the length of the string or you can use the ToString method like so

```
txtBox.Text = double.parse(txtBox.Text).ToString("N0");
```

Alternatively this can also be used

```
txtBox.Text = double.parse(txtBox.Text).ToString("#,#");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Set its mask to something like `###,###`

The rest of your properties can be used just like a regular `TextBox` (including `RightToLeft`).